# how to create a responsive custom label in highchart

Tags: highcharts, label

I create a scatter chart and will add a label on a box that has been specified, I've managed to make his label, but when her screen minimized, do not adjust the position of its labels.

[image]

```
labels: {
    items : [
    {
        html : 'Prioritas 4',
        style : {
            left : '380%',
            top : '60px',
            fontSize : '10px'
        }
    },
    {
        html : 'Prioritas 3',
        style : {
            left : '660%',
            top : '60px',
            fontSize : '10px'
        }
    }
    ]
},
```

and my complete code is

```
$('#ketenagalistrikan-pembenahan-layanan-chart').highcharts({

chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy'
},
title: {
    text: 'Pembenahan Dimensi Layanan'
},
subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: rad-research.com'
},
labels: {
    items : [
    {
        html : 'Prioritas 4',
        style : {
            left : '380%',
            top : '60px',
            fontSize : '10px'
        }
    },
    {
        html : 'Prioritas 3',
        style : {
            left : '660%',
            top : '60px',
            fontSize : '10px'
        }
    }
    ]
},
xAxis: {
    title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'Kepentingan'
    },
    min: -0.5,
    max: 39.3,
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    showLastLabel: true,
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 12.7,
        zIndex: 3

    },{
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 26,
        zIndex: 3
    },{
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 39.3,
        zIndex: 3
    }]
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: 'Kepuasan'
    },
    tickInterval: 8.9,
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    showLastLabel: true,
    plotLines: [{
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 46.2,
        zIndex: 3
    },{
        color: 'black',
        dashStyle: 'dot',
        width: 2,
        value: 55.2,
        zIndex: 3
    }]
},
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        marker: {
            radius: 5,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                }
            }
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x} cm, {point.y} kg'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Marketing',
    data: [[8.75, 45.8]]
},{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: [[15.0, 43.6]]
},{
    name: 'Aktivasi/Instalasi',
    data: [[-0.3, 53.2]]
},{
    name: 'Contact Center',
    data: [[1, 52.2]]
},{
    name: 'Customer Account',
    data: [[-0.3, 60.1]]
},{
    name: 'Field Support',
    data: [[30.5, 40.3]]
},{
    name: 'Billing',
    data: [[37.5, 59.2]]
}]
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Labels in this case are static, so unless you manually redraw them they will will not be responsive.

I prefer another way - you can use renderer and have control rendered objects completely. With the help *axis.toPixels()* method you can easily make them responsive and stays in the fixed value.

Create item on load event:

```
load: function () {
    this.customTexts = [];

    var text = this.renderer.text(
            'Responsive text',
          this.xAxis[0].toPixels(15),
          this.yAxis[0].toPixels(50)
        )
            .css({
            fontSize: '10px'
          })
          .add();

    this.customTexts.push(text);
  },
```

Redraw the item on redraw event:

```
 redraw: function () {
    this.customTexts[0].attr({
        x: this.xAxis[0].toPixels(15),
      y: this.yAxis[0].toPixels(50)
    });
  }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hfev4w7c/

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, click checkmark next to my answer, so it will get accepted.